# How to move my htdocs folder to dropbox and call from there and use that folder for 2 systems?

Tags: php, xampp, dropbox

How to move my htdocs folder to dropbox and call from there?

Me and my friend are on remote location and many times we work on same php projects.

We are on Windows and we use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for PHP development.

At both systems XAMPP is installed on C:/xamppp/

Is it possible to only move htdocs folder to my dropbox folder and use it from there. Then I can share that folder with my friends so he can also use the same htdocs folder in his PC to develop and test.?

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you probably only need to set the paths correctly in each of your Apache configurations.

For example, just create your 'shared_htdocs' folder in Dropbox, share that with your friend, then in your Apache configuration in XAMPP where you have the site (vhost?) defined you need to point to that 'shared_htdocs' folder within Dropbox.

As long as all the code inside is relative and doesn't even need full pathing you should be good.